# No suitable method for adding c++ stl string to C++ rest sdk json object utility string_t

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-c++, casablanca

I want to add a string into C++ rest sdk json object. I tried

```
json::value obj;
obj[L"Login"] = json::value::string();
```

But the problem is this adds only strings as U("str") and not const std::string.
So I can add as

```
obj[L"Login"] = json::value::string(U("Login"));
```

but  not do as follows:

```
json::value obj;
string Login= "login";
obj[L"Login"] = json::value::string(Login);
```

I am using C++ rest sdk 2.8.0.

Comment: What is the problem with `obj[L"key"] = json::value::string(U("str"));`? Just give value to `json::value::string()`

Comment: Edited the question , anyway as I said no const strings are allowed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following type conversion:

```cpp
json::value obj;
string Login= "login";
std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t> > converter;
std::wstring uLogin = converter.from_bytes(Login);
obj[L"Login"] = json::value::string(uLogin);
```

Answer (score 0):

Better switch all your
std::string 
to 
std::**w**string
objects.
cppRest only works with wide strings, so you will end up converting all over the place...